# JxBrowser | Content not rendering

Tags: jxbrowser

I am experiencing an issue related to the displaying of any content within the JxBrowser, but only for 1 specific client PC.
The JxBrowser seems to correctly process the content that is sort of present, because if I click on an area where I know there is a link, the new page is opened (but not rendered too).
The "pages are not displayed" means that the content is completely white. Furthemore, the pointer is repetitively blinking between the normal arrow icon and the waiting circle, as something is going on in the background every about 1 sec.
A previous version of the application that embeds the JxBrowser doesn't produce the same problem.
Later on, I have also upgraded the JxBrowser version from the 6.23 to 6.24.3, but this did not solve.
Deleting any caches produced by the presence of the JxBrowser on the PC did not solve either.
What should I investigate to try and address this situation?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please note that JxBrowser 6 is no longer supported and it's a very old version based on Chromium 69. A lot of popular websites might not work properly in this Chromium version.

If the issue is reproducible only in a specific environment, then it's probably an environment-specific issue. If we are talking about rendering, then usually Chromium cannot render content when there's an issue with GPU drivers and the rendering mode (heavyweight or lightweight).

From our practice, disabling GPU very often helps in such cases. Please try passing the `--disable-gpu` switch and see if it helps. If it doesn't help, then the issue is probably in something else and additional research or even access to this environment is required. But again JxBrowser 6 is no longer supported.

As an option you can try JxBrowser 7 and see if it helps, but it's not that easy because this version has a new API which is not backward-compatible with the previous version.